# Normalized multinomial distribution

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, multinomial-distribution

At some point, in **Bishop**'s book *'Pattern recognition and Machine Learning'*, (p.75) he is talking about multinomial distributions in a classification context, introducing a suitable probability distribution $p(\bf x | \mu)$:[image]

with given constraints for $\bf x$ and $\bf \mu$.

What I don't understand is why the distribution is normalized, i.e. equality 2.27. How does he achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the possible values of $\ \mathbf{x}\ $ are $\ \mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \dots, \mathbf{e}_K\ $, where $\ \mathbf{e}_j\ $ is the unit vector of $\ \mathbb{R}^K\ $ whose $\ j^\text{th}\ $ entry is $1$ and all of whose other entries are $0$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf{x}}\prod_{k=1}^K\mu_k^{x_k}&=\sum_{j=1}^K\prod_{k=1}^K\mu_k^{\left(\mathbf{e}_j\right)_k}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^K \prod_{k=1}^K\mu_k^{\delta_{jk}}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^K\mu_j\\
&=1\ .
\end{align}